# How to set the ITIMER_REAL value using setitimer for a cloned process?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, scheduling

From what I understand, one may set the timer values for a process or thread using the setitimer function. However, doesn't this mean that I need to add this line in the code of the running process?

I am basically trying to use RR scheduling using the SIGALARM signal and setitimer(). I want to define my own quatum. This quantum is basically the timer of a process/thread. WHen the timer expires, the process/thread receives a SIGALRM and I create a handler that does sched_yield() so that the process/thread is pre-empted.

However, as I mentioned above, I do not know how I set the timer values for individual processes without altering the code of the function that I am cloning. Some code below:

```
void RR_switch(int sig) {
        printf("Scheduler yielding for thread id %d\n", syscall(SYS_gettid));
        sched_yield();
}

int main() {
            struct sigaction new_action, old_action;
            new_action.sa_handler = RR_switch;
            sigaction(SIGALRM, &new_action, NULL);
            int pagesize = (int) getpagesize();
            void *t_stack = malloc(pagesize);
            int child_t = clone(&test, t_stack + pagesize, CLONE_THREAD || CLONE_VM || CLONE_CHILD_SETTID || CLONE_VFORK || CLONE_SIGHAND, NULL);
            //raise(SIGSEGV);
            printf("Child thread id from main is %d\n", child_t);
            printf("Main thread id is %d\n", (int) syscall(SYS_gettid));
            return 1;
    }
```

I want the function "test", which is being created through clone, to have a timer value of my choice.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem.  What are you really (big picture) trying to do?  (1) Presumably your parent is simulating the scheduler so you should be able to keep your timers there and send signals to the children.  (2) Putting `sched_yield` inside a signal handler is a bad idea.

Comment: Big picture is I am trying to use RR for my threads with a quantum of my choice. Thanks for (1)...I am gonna try looking into it.